# Compute ℓ₁ distance to hyperbolic parabaloid

Tags: geometry

Given a point $P = (a,b,c)$, how can I compute the $\ell_1$ distance to the closest point on the surface $z = (x)(y-1) + (x-1)(y)$?

(clarification - "closest" meaning "closest by $\ell_1$ distance")

Comment: There are two approaches that come to my mind for this question: first: write a function like f(x,y,z)=sqrt((a-x)^2+(b-y)^2+(c-z)^2) where z is equal to the function you have mentioned in your question. then you should try optimizing this function e.g gradian=0. this will lead to long calculations. the second approach is to find the normal vector to the surface you have mentioned (gradian vector) and then finding the tangent plane to it and finally finding the prependecular distance of the point P and that plane. I believe the second one would work much simpler

Comment: @infinite, he wants to use $l_1$ norm.  Is $l_1$ distance differentiable?

Comment: A detail that probably doesn't make this easier, but I will share anyways - I only care about the case where $0 \leq a, b, c$ and $a + b + c \leq 1$.